# Browser to use in 3G with optimized (in size) content retriaval

Tags: 2.2-froyo, browser

I need a browser to use when running in 3G due to the fact that its speed in my country is far for nice especially in some areas.

My wish it to have a browser that does not download images, video, ads by default but only text. It should still keep a decent pagination.

Then, if I see an image description that interest me, I would like to click and allow download only that image.

Do you know if does exists a browser with these options?

Comment: Twidroyd just release an internal browser that does this. You click a tweet with a link and it loads up just the text on the right side.  A browser app that did this would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Opera](http://www.opera.com/mobile/) browser. It compresses the webpages before sending to your phone.

EDIT: [Here](http://www.engadget.com/2010/09/30/six-android-browsers-enter-the-ring-only-one-reigns-supreme)'s a test done by PC World that Engadget featured showing the Skyfire browser being slightly faster than Opera Mini.